# Inverse of $2\times2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $2\times2$ square matrices such that $AB=I$ Then prove that $BA=I$.

I tried to do it by defining $A$ and $B$ manually by listing the elements but calculations become tedious.
Is there a short way to obtain this result?

One is only allowed to use concept of product of matrices and elementry transformations.

Comment: Perhaps the interesting question is whether there is a very simple proof for the $2 \times 2$ case.

Comment: @Ihf I was going to ask that on MSE and I am going through all of these linked posts and I am not able to find one for the $2\times 2$ case which is simple.

Comment: Here the OP has mentioned the limitations of the tools with which the question has to be answered. I was going through all the other answers and it used linear independent sets, basis etc